# /usr/bin/env is pointing to wrong ruby version. "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, ruby

If I type "rake spec"  I get.
    /usr/bin/env:  ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
 This problem started happening when I uninstalled ruby 1.9.1 and used rvm to install the latest ruby version but now when I type rails -v or rake spec, they're still pointing to the old nonexisting ruby.

This is what my bashrc looks like

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
```

What do I do?

Another error when I try bundle install I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running a Debian'ish distro? Chances are that alternatives were not updated properly during uninstall. Append output of ```update-alternatives --display rails``` to your question. Also append output of ```echo ${PATH}``` and ```which rails```.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that PATH still contains the old ruby location (/usr/bin/env).

Try appending your new ruby bin before $PATH.

Like follows:

```
export PATH=/new_bin/:$PATH
```

If another ruby bin path is before the new one, it will be of higher priority in PATH.